# Knapsack problem - selecting best possible combination of items from 5 sets including 1 item from each set

Tags: algorithm, combinations, knapsack-problem

I have 5 two dimensional arrays containing item value & item price, they look like this

```
A = [
    [1, 1],
    [2, 5],
    [3, 7],
    ...
]
...
...

E = [
    [4, 15],
    [12, 25],
    [33, 57],
    ...
]
```

first column is item `value` and second is `price`

what I want to achieve is final set of 5 values in which each item will be from different starting array, so the final result should look like e.g. `[A[1], B[15], C[46], D[3], E[0]]`, criteria for the elements selected are kinda standard for rucksack problem - best value of all items while keeping the sum of prices of selected elements (second column) under given treshold, e.g. 500

how could I approach it? I literally have no ideas how to do it in proper way, the main issue for me is that I have to pick one item from each set and maximize the output, or maybe there's better approach to this issue than knapsack solving? Only things I can think of currently are

1) precompute all possible results for given params and cache them

2) create price / performance ratio and order items by it and then find some way to find approximate best solution

Comment: Hi stetoc does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming to solve this problem.

Let `dp[i][j]` be the best value with `j` price already used after picking an element from ith array.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j <= 500; j++)
    dp[i][j] = -1;

dp[0][0] = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { // From array A to array E
  for (int j = 0; j < size_of_ith_array; j++) {
    for (int p = 0; p <= 500; p++) {
      if (p >= price[i][j] && dp[i - 1][p - price[i][j]] != -1)
        dp[i][p] = max(dp[i - 1][p - price[i][j]] + value[i][j], dp[i][p]);
      if (p >= price[i][j] && dp[i][p - price[i][j] != -1)
        dp[i][p] = max(dp[i][p - price[i][j]] + value[i][j], dp[i][p]);
    }
  }
}

ans = max(dp[5][0 to 500])
```

Comment: this solution kinda works, but not as expected, I implemented it in my project but it doesn't find combinations matching condition `A+B+C+D+E ≤ 500`, instead it matches `A ≤ 500 && B ≤ 500 && C ≤ 500 && D ≤ 500 && E ≤ 500`, not 100% sure if I made some typo while implementing it or something, will verify it in near future, had to leave this thing until I find spare time for it

Comment: @stetoc no problem, if that still happens you can provide the code and I can help you debug with that:D

Comment: This logic is flawed. When you loop over p inside each jth set of items, you reset the weight to 0 so the weight isn't sum of all previous items, only total weight per set.

Comment: @PuiHoLam You're right, just fixed it, thanks!